# how to fix SQLException "no suitable driver found for jdbc "?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am trying to connect to my coffee database to insert data but every-time I run the code it says

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/coffeeZone
```

iv'e tried using this Class.forName("dbc:derby://localhost:1527/coffeeZone");
I also have the mysql jdbc driver on my mac

```
    String query="INSERT INTO `coffeeZone`.`branch` (`branch_Num`, `admin_id`, `Street`, `Nieghbourhood`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?');";

          try{

      PreparedStatement ps;
      String f="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/coffeeZone [coffee on COFFEE]";

      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            f, "coffee", "1234"); 
       ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, bno);
        ps.setString(2, strt);
       ps.setString(3, nbh);
        ps.setString(4, ci);
   if  (ps.executeUpdate()>0){


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete! a new branch is added !");
               }else
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User already exists");
               }

    }        catch (SQLException ex) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }                                       

    }
```

Comment: "jdbc:derby://", "jdbc:mysql://". Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using jdbc:derby://

Comment: Class.forName requires a class name, not uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to call `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` prior establishing your connection, based on this connection string: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname`.

Edit:  If you're using Derby, you need this: `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");`  (https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html).

Did you post the exact error that you're getting?  It seems strange that the error refers to a MySql connection but the code uses a Derby connection string.

Comment: OP stated she is using Derby

Comment: Use of `Class.forName` shouldn't be necessary due to autoloading of drivers (unless this is a web application, but then you shouldn't even be using `DriverManager`). Also given the URL includes a host name and port, the `EmbeddedDriver` is the wrong one.